# Why php code is not working?

Tags: php, html

I want to display a database table in my .php web page.
I use the following code:

```
<?php
        include('../dbconnect.php');
        $det= SELECT * FROM user ;
        $result=mysqli_query($con,$det);
         mysqli_close($con);

         while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
         {

            echo '<table style="width: 100%">
                <tr>';
                    echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
                    $del=$row['uid'];
                    echo '<td><a href=functions/deleteuser.php?id=' .$del.'>Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>';

         }
    ?>
```

But, when I include this code, the whole web page appears as blank. Without this code, the page works fine. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: This: `$det= SELECT * FROM user ;`

Comment: Where are the quotes around your query?

Comment: whats in your dbconnect.php? Can you provide the code in it??

Comment: You're missing quotes around your query, and at the end of your second echo line.

Comment: ...and now you'll have answers like *spam*!! :)

Comment: you should enclose your select query

Comment: Enable error reporting or check your log files for the error.

Comment: I don't need a logfile to see that the op has no idea how code is written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be like this

```
$det = 'SELECT * FROM user';
```

Comment: @codeSlayer i have a doubt even if it is used in that way mysqli_close($con); is used before fetching the data whether it works

Comment: i don't know why it is still works, but i saw same example in net that uses the same code.

Answer (score 4):

The query should be used in double/single quotes. Like this.

```
$det = 'SELECT * FROM user' ;
```

Answer (score 2):

query not quoted try this

```
$det= "SELECT * FROM `user`";
```

Answer (score -3):

`mysqli_close($con);` should be at the bottom after your while loop. Try doing this.

Comment: wrong...quotes missing in sql..values is there in `$det` ..btw i dint downvote!! ;)